# Packaging CMake components for Debian

Tags: packaging, deb, cmake

I have a single upstream source package using cmake and I'd like to package it as two binary debian packages.

```
$ tree proj
proj/
├── app1.c
├── app2.c
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

Upstream's `CMakeLists.txt` was already written with this in mind.  They use the COMPONENTS argument of [`install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html)

```
$ cat proj/CMakeLists.txt
include(GnuInstallDirs)

add_executable(app1 app1.c)
install(
  TARGETS app1 
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
  COMPONENT app1)

add_executable(app2 app2.c)
install(
  TARGETS app2
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
  COMPONENT app2)
```

To compile/install locally, it's pretty easy:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ../proj -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  # Configure
$ cmake --build .                                  # Build
$ cmake -DCOMPONENT=app1 -P cmake_install.cmake    # Install app1 component
$ cmake -DCOMPONENT=app2 -P cmake_install.cmake    # Install app2 component
```

But how would you build a `debian/rules` file for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard debhelper `debain/rules` file might look like this (buildsystem automatically detects cmake in newer compat levels).

```
%:
        dh $@    # --buildsystem=cmake  <-- older compat levels may need this
```

This will effectively run `make install DESTDIR=debian/tmp`.  But that puts everything into one destination, requiring you to write `debian/*.install` files to manually to split it up (see [dh_install(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_install.1.en.html)).  This is the normal way to turn a monolithic cmake source into multiple binaries and there's a good guide for that in Debian's manual [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch08.en.html#cmake-multi).

However, upstream has done that work for you by defining COMPONENT installs.

To take advantage of that, override your own install recipe to specify package/component association:

```
include /usr/share/dpkg/architecture.mk

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_install:
        sed -i -e 's/\-P/\-DCOMPONENT\=app1\ \-P/g' obj-$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/Makefile
        dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/app1

        sed -i -e 's/\-DCOMPONENT\=app1/\-DCOMPONENT\=app2/g' obj-$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/Makefile
        dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/app2
```

The root of `debian/<binary_package_name>` represents `/` in that binary package.

I'm a little disappointed in the `sed` commands.  I was hoping to do it by passing `-- -DCOMPONENT=app1` to dh_auto_install directory.  Instead these commands edit the Makefile auto-generated by cmake.  This solution presumes you are using `make`, and that the only `-P` string is going to be in your install commands (which seem to be the case for the projects I've checked so far).  I'm happy to accept edits to this answer with a better solution.

Note:  Kitware (cmake developer) is working on a new debhelper extension [dh-cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/debian/dh-cmake) which looks like it'll make this even easier.  However, as of Debian 10 (buster) it's not yet available.

Comment: You should to use `DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH`, otherwise your package will fail when cross-building. Also, you should include `/usr/share/dpkg/architecture.mk` explicitly to be able to use these variables in all cases (yeah, I know, most `debian/rules` don’t, but they’re incorrect). And I haven’t tried this with this package, but it might be possible to use `dh_auto_install` with additional flags instead of calling `cmake` directly, something like `dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/app1 -- -DCOMPONENT=app1`.

Comment: Thanks for `DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH`!  Regarding `dh_auto_install`, the `-DCOMPONENT=app1` gets passed to `make install` not `cmake`.  `make install` fails with `make:invalid option -- 'D'`.  I've also noticed some other limitations with what I've described above: `install(DIRECTORY` doesn't seem to take `DESTDIR` into account.  I'll post an update or a bug report link when I figure that out.

Comment: Yep, `dh_auto_install` was a much better solution.  They way I did it had too many bugs.  This also removes the need for DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH completely. I pass `-DCOMPONENT`, from make to cmake, we just had to add an extra `--`.

Comment: Ok, found a solution, but it's sloppy.  I'm using `sed` to edit the cmake-generated makefile directly.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `cmake` is only invoked during the “configure” phase; the following phases use the generated Makefiles directly. So you’d have to run `dh_auto_configure` twice, once per component, and then the same for all the following phases... Not a good idea really.

Comment: Probably the best approach is to either duplicate the component definitions in `.install` files, or to use your initial `cmake` calls with `DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH`, but overriding `dh_auto_install` instead of `dh_install`.